# GATHER verb are not interpreting small/simple words, only phrases

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

i have a Twiml that return a GATHER verb, but when i answer in the phone with just one simple word, like "sim" (Brazillian word for "yes"), Twilio do not transcript anything and just hangup the call because of the automatic timeout.

Anyone with the same issue? There is a way to control this behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Have you tried making the value of `speechTimeout` longer or using the `hints` attribute containing a list of words or phrases that Twilio should expect during recognition? You could also [set the language to be Portuguese from Brazil](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#languagetags) maybe. It would help if you shared some of your code, but that might look something like this:

```
<Response>
    <Gather input="speech dtmf" speechTimeout="10" hints = "sim">
    </Gather>
</Response>
```